How to modify this git alias so it can be run without the need to put multiword commands in quotation?
I have this alias:
git config --global alias.all '!f() { ls -R -d */.git | xargs -I{} bash -c "echo {} && git -C {}/../ $1"; }; f'

It currently works fine when I run it like :
git all status
But if want to pass arguments to status I need to run it like : git all "status -sb"
What do I need to change in my original command so i don't need to quote anything?

I think this will do what you want:
git config --global alias.all \
  '!'"f() { ls -R -d */.git | xargs -I{} bash -c 'echo {} && git -C {}/../ \"\$@\"' -- \"\$@\"; }; f"

Or just open your git config file in an editor and add to the [alias] section:
all = "!f() { ls -R -d */.git | xargs -I{} bash -c 'echo {} && git -C {}/../ \"$@\"' -- \"$@\"; }; f"

That's the same thing, but avoids the annoyance of working around shell quote interpretation. With this alias in place, running in a directory that contains two git repositories:
Without additional arguments:
$ git all status
c-hello-world/.git
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
rust-hello-world/.git
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

And with -sb:
$ git all status -sb
c-hello-world/.git
## master...origin/master
rust-hello-world/.git
## master...origin/master


While that works, I would probably write it like this instead:
git config --global alias.all \
  '!bash -c "find . -name .git -execdir pwd \; -execdir git \"\$@\" \;" --'


Thanks, this works perfectly!

See my update which shows a simpler way of writing the same functionality.

Very elegant. Thanks!

I wonder why the "$@" needs to be escaped. If it's because a shell is executing the entire thing command, wouldn't '!find . -name .git -execdir pwd \; -execdir git "$@" \;' work as well? (Also -printf "%h\n" instead of -execdir pwd)

The version of find installed on my work machine doesn't support -printf, so i am stuck with -execdir.

@muru the "$@" in my answer needs to be escaped because it's inside a double quoted string, and we want it expanded by the child bash, not the parent bash. I actually tried your suggestion (!find ...) first, but $@ ends up incorrect (try setting git config --global alias.all '!echo "$@"'), and then look at the output of e.g. git all status).

Hmm, I had a look at what's going on using strace, and it seems that for an alias !foo bar, got executes sh -c 'foo bar "$@"' 'foo bar' <arguments>. So it's not about which shell is doing the expansion, but Git being a bit too smart here for us and inserting extra code. Which explains why wherever OP got the idea for the code in the question used functions. In that case, I'd actually agree with them - a function is simpler than an extra shell call, so '!f() { find . -name .git -execdir pwd \; -execdir git "$@" \;' ; }; f' works as expected.

A more robust version that will handle any types of whitespace or quoting, because it doesn't concatenate and re-split the arguments:
git config --global alias.all '!f() { for gdir in */.git; do printf %s\\n "$gdir"; git -C "$gdir"/../ "$@"; done;}; f'

